# How to interpret this command chaining?

Tags: bash

```
[root@localhost /]# ( ./address_to_char;cat) | ./overflow
```

How does  `( ./address_to_char;cat)`  work here?

What's different from `./address_to_char|./overflow`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outputs of both `./address_to_char` and `cat` are piped to `./overflow` as a single, continuous stream of data.

1. First, `./address_to_char` is run, and its output is redirected to `./overflow`'s input.
2. When `./address_to_char` exits, `cat` is started, and its output is attached to the still-running `./overflow` process in the same way.

   Since `cat` was run with no files specified, it reads from stdin (in this case, your keyboard).

Comment: @grawity,when will `cat` in subshell exit?

Comment: @kernel: `cat` exits upon reaching the end of its input. In this case, it reads from keyboard, and will exit when you press the "EOF" key (by default Ctrl-D).

Comment: @grawity,but after testing it seems it will also exit when `./overflow` exits,weird...or is that normal?

Comment: @kernel: It's normal. When the right side (`./overflow`) exits, the left side doesn't have anywhere to write to, and -- AFAIK -- gets killed by signal `SIGPIPE`.

Comment: @grawity,that solves most of my doubt,but still one, how can `./overflow` get executed before `cat` exits?

Comment: @kernel: Any "modern" OS (since approx. 1960's) supports running multiple processes at once. This means that both sides of [a pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29) are started at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Well the parentheses open a sub shell and the semi colon will run the commands sequentially.

So in this case, you are running `./address_to_char` then `cat` in a subshell.

Comment: How does the subshell interact with `./overflow`?

Comment: stderr and stdout are returned and piped into overflow

Comment: The output of the subshell is then redirected into ./overflow

Comment: It seems there's no difference from `./address_to_char |  ./overflow`,right?